# Reference Request: Carnot Groups over Complexes

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, cv.complex-variables, lie-groups

Is there a theory of complex (analytic) Carnot groups and Caratheodory metrics?

Comment: I searched the keywords "sub-kahler" and "nilpotent", maybe check https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0037446616050128

Comment: This is interesting and the search makes sense.  I'll read this paper.  Thanks YCor